# How I can prevent reloading data second time after configuration change using ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Reloading data after every rotation
I fetch data in onCreate and observe in onCreateView().
I want to know after rotating the phone(or after configuration changes data is reloaded again as a result I have these logs before rotation

```
fetchConfig ->observe
```

and after rotating
I have

```
observe ->fetchConfig ->observe
```

How I can prevent reloading data second time?
I have added in fetchConfig()

```
if(customerConfigData.value==null) {}
```

but I am not sure is it the best solution

```
private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by lazyViewModel()
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
viewModel.fetchConfig()
}

 override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
viewModel.customerConfigData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
Log.i("test","observe")
})
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false)
}


 fun fetchConfig() {
Log.i("test","fetchConfig")

  uiScope.launch {
    val configEndpoint = EnigmaRiverContext.getExposureBaseUrl().append("v1/customer").append(AppConstants.CUSTOMER_UNIT)
        .append("businessunit").append(AppConstants.BUSINESS_UNIT).append("defaultConfig").append("?preview=true")

    val parsedData = homeRepository.fetchConfig(configEndpoint, GetConfigCall())
    customerConfigMutableData.postValue(parsedData)
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution I think would be to move call to `fetchConfig()` in to the `init` block of your `ViewModel`

Comment: this is actually a clever solution. Simple and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, your method has a parameter called `savedInstanceState: Bundle?`. This bundle is able to save the state of the app when the configuration changes. So, you can put here any flag you want.
Now, remember that ViewModels are designed to be implemented with a good code base. So, you need to separate the Ui layer from the business layer. The fetch configuration method should be in another class which doesn't depend on the Android lifecycle. I strongly recommend reading these articles.

> https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090
>
> https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

In conclusion. Your solution is not the best. The best approach is to implement a correct layer for fetching the info in a way that it doesn't depend on the Android lifecycle.

Comment: You mean keep state if it data is fetched or not in savedInstanceState?

Comment: That can be an approach. But again, the data must be in somewhere else. That place should make the validation about what retrieve to the view model.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by  "That place should make the validation about what retrieve to the view model." Can you explain, please ?

Comment: Fredy Trujiillo
I have read the arcticles you posted,Thanks
if I combine with savedInstanceState
But in a case `The activity is created after being stopped by the system:`
in this case savedInstanceState would not be null but data in viewModel is null
how should I know that data is null ?

Answer (score 0):

I too had similar issue. I was suggested to try Event wrapper for LiveData, it had solved my problem:)

Here's the link:
[How to stop LiveData event being triggered more than Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688838/how-to-stop-livedata-event-being-triggered-more-than-once/54689326#54689326)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to add a comment. Only way to convey message was to add answer.